# Distribution function of X given a table of probability function

Tags: probability-distributions

I am shown a table with x and f(x) where f is the probability function of a random variable X.

```
x    |  1   |   2   |   3   |
-----------------------------
f(x) | 1/2  |  1/4  |  1/4  |
```

What would I need to do to find the distribution function of X from this information?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cumulative distribution function, denoted (capital) $F$, is defind by $F(x)=\Pr(X\le x)$.  The usual mistake here is to write $F(1)=1/2$, $F(2)=3/4$, $F(3) = 1$, and think that's it.  That's correct as far as it goes, but the domain of $F$ is the entire set of real numbers, not just those in the support of the probability distribution.  So, for example,
$$
F(2.3) = \Pr(X\le 2.3) = \Pr(X=\text{ either }0\text{ or }1) = \frac34.
$$
You need to write a piecewise definition, saying what $F(x)$ is for $x<1$, for $1\le x<2$, for $2\le x<3$, and for $x\ge 3$.

Comment: @rhino18 And be sure to pay careful attention to the difference between $<$ and $\leq$ when you follow the directions in Michael Hardy's last sentence above.